# How to add cdata to node to xml in php

Tags: php

this code generate following o/p

```
 $dom = new DomDocument("1.0", "ISO-8859-1");
  $root = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement( "Questions")); 
  $sxe = simplexml_import_dom( $dom ); 
  $question = $sxe->addchild("Question");
  $question->addAttribute('id', $Question_Id);
  $question->addAttribute('type', $type);                       
  $question->addChild('Option_One', $Option_One);
  $dom->formatOutput = true; 
  $xmlString = $dom->saveXML(); 
  $dom->save("{$Campaign_Name}.xml");
```

o/p is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Questions>
  <Question id="1" type="mcma">
    <Option_One>Bhuntar</Option_One>
  </Question>
</Questions>
```

now i want to add CDATA to the Question.

Comment: what is the question? Why can't you simply concatenate CDATA open and close strings to the text?

Comment: createCDATASection gives me error

Comment: $question->appendChild($dom->createCDATASection( $Questiontext)); this line gives me error

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix different object types and you will be fine

```
$dom = new DomDocument("1.0", "ISO-8859-1");
  $root = $dom->appendChild( $questions = $dom->createElement( "Questions")); 
  $questions->appendChild($question = $dom->createElement('Question'));
  $question->setAttribute('id', $Question_Id);
  $question->setAttribute('type', $type);                       
  $question->appendChild($dom->createElement('Option_One', $Option_One));
  $question->appendChild($dom->createCDATASection( $Questiontext));
  $dom->formatOutput = true; 
  $xmlString = $dom->saveXML(); 
  $dom->save("{$Campaign_Name}.xml");
```